# HTML textfield with suggestions

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I am trying to create a textfield where i can input text and get suggestions from list entries (that are narrowed down with every input character). Where the list is loaded from my backend.

```
<label>Owner:
    <input #owner (keypress)="searchOwner(owner.value)" list="owners" name="owner" /></label>
  <datalist id="owners">
    <option *ngFor="let elem in owners" value="{{elem.id}}">{{elem.name}}</option>
  </datalist>
```

This should (and does load the right values that should be returned into the owners list.
However, it doesnt display the list as options. How can i accieve this?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nva91.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Vue-multiselect for this functionality in my app and it works well for me. [Here is a link to check it out.](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/)

The other thing you can do is loop through each of your options and add them as options/values to your option list which looks like you are trying to do above. That is Angulars way of looping through options, but you may want to use Javascript if you don't have angular on the page.